# Running Junit tests even if build failed because of other files that do not depend on the test

Tags: java, junit

I have a Java project on intellij with multiple exercices to do for the semester. Some tests are associated with these exercises. However, I cannot run the tests as the build fail because some methods are not yet implemented in other files.

For example, I have a StackWithTwoQueues.java file that I implemented and associated with that I have StackWithTwoQueuesTest.java file. When I run this file, I get "build failed" because some methods in a file MinMaxHeap.java do not contain return value (which makes sense because I'm not worked on this exercise yet).

Is there a way to run the test and ignoring this "build failed" ?

Comment: You could make those methods return null just for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's important to understand the difference between running a build and running a test.

A test runs on compiled code, your code is compiled when you run a build.

To be able to build, the code must be complete with no fatal errors that prevent the code from compiling.

Having half-written code, in this case a method without a return type, will prevent the code from compiling. So to answer your question, no it's not possible.

To solve this, you could:

- Comment out the half-written methods, and anywhere that they are called from, you can use a double `//` to do this, or a block comment using `/*commented out*/` across multiple lines.
- Insert some placeholders into the code. For example if change the method declaration to have `void` as the return type. This means it does not expect anything to be returned.

```
     public static void voidMethod() {
```

- Just return null, or empty string, or an int from these methods.

Basically, as you don't care about these methods, just keep them out of the way.
Hope that helps.